# Ebean using OR in query

Tags: ebean

I'm trying to make a query where I want to check if either the email or name of a user starts with a given string. In a sql query I would write this using

```
name like 'queryString%' or email like 'queryString%'
```

In ebean query I would expect to write something like:

```
find.where().or(like('name', 'queryString%'), like('email', 'queryString%'));
```

The problem is that the or takes in an expression, not an expressionlist, which is what I get when writing

```
find.where().like(...,...)
```

As I understand it doing a query like this:

```
find.where().like(.., ...).like(..., ...)
```

is using AND.

How can I write such a query using ebean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your second attempt is almost OK, you have to use just `com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like()` inside the `or()`

```
find.where().or(
        com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("email", email + "%"),
        com.avaje.ebean.Expr.like("name",  name + "%")
).findUnique();
```

of course you can use an import for shorter code::

```
import com.avaje.ebean.Expr;

...
find.where().or(Expr.like("email", email + "%"),Expr.like("name", name + "%")).findUnique();
```

Check the API in Javadoc: http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Expr.html

Comment: I could not find this documented anywhere on the avaje ebean docs page, and I'm new to ebean. Thanks for the answer though!;)

Comment: Your example shows two alternatives. How do you OR more than 2 things?

Comment: @TomL, I'm afraid that only sensible way is building queries with http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/RawSql.html - it's not as comfortable as common finders, however it's pretty flexible. Otherwise you'd need to wrap `or` with `or` with `or` In case when you have fully dynamic amount of conditions to check wrapping `or` expressions  makes no sense.

Answer (score 7):

Note that you can also use fluid style via disjunction(), conjunction() and endJunction().

For example:

```
Query<Conversation> query = Ebean.find(Conversation.class)
  .where().eq("group.id", groupId)
  .disjunction()
    .conjunction()
      .eq("open", false).eq("participants.user.id", userId)
    .endJunction()
    .eq("open", true)
  .endJunction()
  .orderBy("whenCreated desc");
```

And an example using type safe query beans it is similar but instead uses or(), and(), endAnd(), endOr() ... rather than disjunction()/conjunction() etc.

```
List<Customer> customers
  = new QCustomer()
  .billingAddress.city.equalTo("Auckland")
  .version.between(1,100)
  .billingAddress.country.equalTo(nz)
  .registered.before(new Date())
  .or()
    .id.greaterThan(1)
    .and()
      .name.icontains("Jim")
      .inactive.isTrue()
    .endAnd()
  .endOr()
  .orderBy()
    .name.asc()
    .id.desc()
  .findList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the query can be written in fluid style using disjunction():

```
find.where().disjunction()
  .like("email", email + "%")
  .like("name",  name + "%")
  .findUnique();
```

If there is more that one disjunction() / conjunction() then you use `endJunction()` to end that OR and AND group.

In the example there is only a single OR group required so `endJunction()` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was trying to figure out how to do a nested series of AND/OR clauses in the query. This seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: `disjunction()` and `conjunction()` gives much more flexibility than `or()` or `and()` especially when there is requirement for using more than 2 expressions  in each.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **raw(String,Object[])** see [Raw expressions](https://ebean.io/docs/query/where#raw) :

```
new QMyEntity().raw("name like ? or email like ?","yourName","yourEmail").findOne();
```

Answer (score -1):

about more then 2 OR LIKE, you can try this...

```
where.or(Expr.contains("name", inquire.q),
                    Expr.or(Expr.contains("address", inquire.q), Expr.contains("description", inquire.q)));
```